# The use of the preposition "about" with the verb "wonder"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Tell me please if the preposition *about* change the meaning of the following sentence.

> I have noticed a tattoo on your left shoulder, and I wonder (**about**) what it means.

And now I wonder if could use the verb *wonder*
in the present progressive tense in the sentence, and would it have the same meaning as in the present simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **wonder about** the tattoo:  what it means, when she got it, whether it was painful, whether she was drunk when she got it, whatever.

But you **wonder *what it means*** not "about what".